# Passing a password to KLOG from within a script, using `subprocess.POPEN`

Tags: python, subprocess, system-calls

A series of applications I'm writing require that the user be able to read from a filesystem with [KLOG](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/klog.afs.1.html) authentication. Some functions require the user to have KLOG tokens (i.e., be authenticated) and others don't. I wrote a small Python decorator so that I can refactor the "you must be KLOGed" functionality within my modules:

```
# this decorator is defined in ``mymodule.utils.decorators``
def require_klog(method):
    def require_klog_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # run the ``tokens`` program to see if we have KLOG tokens
        out = subprocess.Popen('tokens', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        # the tokens (if any) are located in lines 4:n-1
        tokens_list = out.stdout.readlines()[3:-1]
        if tokens_list == []:
            # this is where I launch KLOG (if the user is not authenticated)
            subprocess.Popen('klog')
        out = method(*args, **kwargs)
        return out
    return require_klog_wrapper

# once the decorator is defined, any function can use it as follows:
from mymodule.utils.decorators import require_klog
@require_klog
def my_function():
 # do something (if not KLOGed, it SHUOLD ask for the password... but it does not!)
```

It is all very simple. Except when I tried to apply the following logic: "if the user is not KLOGed, run KLOG and ask for the password".

I do this using `subprocess.Popen('klog')` and the `password:` prompt does come up to the terminal. However, when I write the password it actually is echoed back to the terminal and, worse, nothing happens upon hitting return.

Edit:

After Alex's fast and correct response I solved the problem as follows:

- I erased all the `*.pyc` files from my module's directory (yes - this made a difference)
- I used `getpass.getpass()` to store the password in a local variable
- I called the KLOG command with the `-pipe` option
- I passed the locally-stored password to the pipe via the pipe's `write` method

Below is the corrected decorator:

```
def require_klog(method):
    def require_klog_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # run the ``tokens`` program to see if we have KLOG tokens
        out = subprocess.Popen('tokens', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        # the tokens (if any) are located in lines 4:n-1
        tokens_list = out.stdout.readlines()[3:-1]
        if tokens_list == []:
            args = ['klog', '-pipe']
            # this is the custom pwd prompt 
            pwd = getpass.getpass('Type in your AFS password: ') 
            pipe = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            # here is where the password is sent to the program
            pipe.stdin.write(pwd) 
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    return require_klog_wrapper
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, your script (or something else it's spawning later) and the subprocess running `klog` are "competing" for the `/dev/tty` -- and the subprocess is losing (after all, you're not calling the `wait` method of the object returned from `subprocess.Popen`, to ensure you wait until it terminates before continuing, so a race condition of some kind would be hardly surprising).

If a `wait` does not suffice, I would work around this by putting

```
pwd = getpass.getpass('password:')
```

in the Python code (with an `import getpass` at the top of course), then running `klog` with the `-pipe` argument and `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`, and writing `pwd` to that pipe (with a call to the [communicate](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method of the object returned from `subprocess.Popen`).

Comment: Thanks Alex - the `-pipe` + `getpass()` solution worked great.